# NSOperationQueue NSOperation(QOS_Legacy) issue

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, nsoperationqueue

I deployed my code before Swift 2 came out and with Crashlytics I get about 2-3 crashes a day supposedly in this func. I can't, for the life of me, figure out what's going on. I have thousands of users but out of the myriad that use the app I end up getting about 8-10 a day where Crashlytics reports something wrong.

The error is:

```
 _TFZFC11 GProxy8GetAsyncFMS0_U_S_14Deserializable__FTGCS_10
GRequestQ__8callbackFGCS_11 GResponseGSaQ0___
T__T_U_FTGSQCSo6NSData_GSQCSo13 NSURLResponse_GSQCSo7 NSError__T_ 
(GProxy.swift:141)
```

I am making a request to my server and processing an array back and doing something with it in my callback (further up the chain somewhere else in my app).

Here is the code:

```
 class func GetAsync<R, T: Deserializable>(request: GRequest<R>, callback: (GResponse<Array<T>>) -> ())
    {
        var list = Array<T>()
        var response = GResponse<Array<T>>()
        let serverRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: API_URL + request.Url)!)
        serverRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(serverRequest,
            completionHandler: {
                data, r, error in

                if error != nil {
                    response.Status = .ERROR
                } else {
                   do
                    {
                        let responseArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSArray

                        for item: AnyObject in responseArray {
                            let row = T(dict: item as! NSDictionary)
                            list.append(row)
                        }
                        response = GResponse<Array<T>>(status: ResponseCode.OK, value: list)
                    }
                   catch let err as NSError{
                             //I now log here (this is new code, before I was not)
                    }
                }
                callback(response)
        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

Are there any major faux pas here where a crash may occur? See any glaring errors or potential concerns? I don't have the actual source anymore of when I deployed (I made changes to this class so I don't recall what line 141 is, but the crash message seems to do with NSURLResponse and the like. Any thoughts?

Thanks so much!

Comment: did you get any clue on this ?

Comment: no I didn't but I also haven't had any major errors so my assumption is this is OK.

Comment: The code is full of force unwraps, and a lot of potential issues. What exactly is the crash? the backtrace?